# "Factorization" of the solutions set of a system of linear diophantine equations over non-negative integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integer-partitions, integer-programming, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose we have a system of linear diophantine equations over non-negative integers:
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
&Ax=b\\
&x\in \mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq0}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
where $A$ is a matrix of size $m\times n$, $a_{ij}\in \mathbb{N},~b\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $S_{b'}$ be the set of solutions of this system, with right-hand side $b'$. $S_{b'}=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq 0}| Ax=b'\}$

How can we find such $b_1$ and $b_2$ that: $b_1+b_2=b$ and $S_{b}=S_{b_1}+S_{b_2}=\{x+y|x\in S_{b_1},~y\in S_{b_2}\}$?

Informally, I want to find a split of the "knapsack" into two parts, so that any solution of the original knapsack problem can be divided into two parts so that these two parts are solutions to these two subproblems.

The problem can be reformulated without $b_2$:

Let $x\geq y \Leftrightarrow x-y\in \mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq 0}$. Find a $b_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x\in S_{b} \exists y\in S_{b_1}: x\geq y$. Then it is obvious that $S_{b_2} =\{x\in S_{b}-S_{b_1}| x\geq \vec{0}\}$ and $b_2=b-b_1$.

Comment: I don't know if such splitting must exist even for a single diophantine equation. Take for instance the equation $2x + 2y = 2$. It's solution set is $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$, but those cannot be written as sums of solutions of $2x + 2y = 1$, for which there are none.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza , Yes, I agree, splitting does not always exist. But there are examples when it does exist, for example: $2x+3y+4z=9$. It has 3 solutions: $\{(1,1,1),(0,3,0),(3,1,0)\}$. If we split the right-hand side into 3 and 6, we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&2x+3y+4z=6\\
&2x+3y+4z=3
\end{aligned}
$$

Obviously, the second equation has one solution $(0,1,0)$ and the first one $\{(0,2,0),(3,0,0),(1,0,1)\}$. It can be seen that: $S_{6}+S_{3}=S_{9}$.